# Why is it showing Index is outside of the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, reverse

I am getting index is out of bounds at lines 33 and 46. Why is this?
I am trying to reverse the array. I know what the error code means, but I do not know why I am getting it.
Line 33 - string reversed = ReverseArray(crafting);
Line 46 -  return reverseCraft[5];

```
        //make an array to be reversed
        string[] craftArray = new string[5] { "Iron", "Stone", "Copper", "Steel", "Clay" };


        //create a variable to hold return value
        string[] crafting = new string[5];





        //function call the ReverseCraft method
        string reversed = ReverseArray(crafting);

        //Report the calculation to the user
        Console.Write("The array reversed is" + reversed);



    }
    public static string ReverseArray(string[] craft)
    {
        //create a variable and reverse
        string[] reverseCraft = new string[5] { craft[4], craft[3], craft[2], craft[1], craft[0] };
        //return value
        return reverseCraft[5];

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `reverseCraft[5]` should be `[4]`. Since arrays are zero based.

Comment: Your line count is also out of bounds

Comment: The method ReverseArray should return an array of strings, not a string.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but in the future I would firstly use Array.Reverse(). If you are going to write a function to do something like this I would recommend using a for loop with bounds checks..

Answer (score 2):

Your reverse method has a wrong signature. It should return `string[]`, like this:

```
public static string[] ReverseArray(string[] craft) {
    //create a variable and reverse
    string[] reverseCraft = new string[5] { craft[4], craft[3], craft[2], craft[1], craft[0] };
    //return value
    return reverseCraft;
}
```

With this code in place, all you need to do is print the result properly:

```
string[] reversed = ReverseArray(crafting);
//Report the calculation to the user
Console.Write("The array reversed is " + string.Join(", ", reversed));
```

Comment: Okay thank you. Is there another way to do this instead of using string.join?

Comment: @Xoax Yes, you can write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing an error on the line

return reverseCraft[5];

because there is no reverseCraft[5].

The first element of reverseCraft is reverseCraft[0] and the last element is reverseCraft[4].

Comment: Fixed this part. Thank you